# Moving one page to another page? - JQuerymobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using the jquerymobile for developing app. Here I want to move the one page to another page. I used the $.mobile.changePage("html file"); But If I move the page then the page displays as a normal html page.(The controls looks like normal html page controls. Nothing assigned in the UI)

What I missed ? Please Point out me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug, try running jquery mobile together with jquery 1.4.3 instead of 1.4.4

Also the default way to do such a thing is to use a normal `<a href=` and let jqm do the magic. It does the same, but it will also work in non-js browsers. Give more details if that's not the case.